# Print column with a specific value in python

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

I am using Colab.I am trying to print data form only NY,NC, SC State

```
confirmed_cases_USA, deaths_USA = get_confirmed_deaths_tuple_df (USA_covid_data)

# selecting rows based on condition PA, IL,OH,GA ,NC 

options = ['NC',"PA"] 
#options = ['NC',"PA","IL","OH","GA"] 
confirmed_cases_Selected = confirmed_cases_USA[confirmed_cases_USA ['State'].isin(options)] 
deaths_Selected= deaths_USA [deaths_USA ['State'].isin(options)]

print(confirmed_cases_Selected.head())
print(deaths_Selected.head())
```

output is :

```
countyFIPS            County Name         State  ...  9/19/20  9/20/20  
1921           0  Statewide Unallocated    NC  ...     1166     1166     1166
1922       37001        Alamance County    NC  ...     3695     3728     3749
1923       37003       Alexander County    NC  ...      483      485      488
1924       37005       Alleghany County    NC  ...      219      220      220
1925       37007           Anson County    NC  ...      549      552      553




    countyFIPS            County Name State  ...  9/19/20  9/20/20  
1921           0  Statewide Unallocated    NC  ...        0        0        
1922       37001        Alamance County    NC  ...       48       54       54
1923       37003       Alexander County    NC  ...        5        5        5
1924       37005       Alleghany County    NC  ...        0        0        0
1925       37007           Anson County    NC  ...        4        4        4
```

I am trying to Group the data by state first and then get the total to confirm case of the state

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `get_confirmed_deaths_tuple_df` does but it doesn't look like a DataFrame.

`USA_covid_data['State'].isin(options)` should return a boolean mask containing `True` and `False`. Return the values that satisfy the `True` condition with `USA_covid_data[USA_covid_data['State'].isin(options)]`

It should look something like this.

```
confirmed_cases_USA, deaths_USA = get_confirmed_deaths_tuple_df(USA_covid_data[USA_covid_data['State'].isin(options)])
```